# How to add a navigation controller/bar to iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer

I am currently trying to add a navigation bar for every screen. However I want to programmatically add different types of buttons available on different screens, specifically on the different slide drawer menu items. Also, I want to be able to have a back button for nested screens.

I have read about the navigation controller and I see there is just a navigation bar that I can add to my xib file, but not sure how to implement it exactly. If I add a navigation bar to the xib file do I have to reference it somehow in my controller or should adding it be enough, because adding this line does not add the items to the navigation bar.

This is the code I add in my MainViewController.m file:

```
//add navigation top bar items
        UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

        NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where ever you initially create your `MainViewController` (and most likely assign it to the windows [`rootViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) property) wrap this in a [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = [MainViewController new];
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
```

You code in your question is then correct, and those `UIBarButtonItem`s will then show in the navigation bar.

Comment: Ok and if I want to add a back button do I still surround the controller with a navigation controller, for controllers nested in a controller? Also, not sure if their is a way to make the slide drawer wrapping all drawer items without having to include the code in each drawer item's controller?

Comment: Yes, the back button will automatically be added when you [push](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) a view controller on to the navigation stack `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`